# Condition to limit between 2 characters

Tags: c, char

I'm writing code that need to limit the use to enter characters that be only from `A` to `H`. Greater then `H` should not be accepted.
I saw that with numbers I can use that like:

```
if (input == 0 - 9) return 1;
```

But, how I do that `A` to `H` (`char`)?

Comment: input>=0 && input<=9  but with the chars...
input>='A' && input<='H'

Comment: _i saw that in numbers i can use that like: if(input == 0 - 9)_ No, this will only return 1 in case `input` is equal to `-9`.

Comment: *i saw that in number i can use that like: `if(input == 0 - 9)`* .... where did you see this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C Standard does not specify that character encoding should be ASCII, though it is likely. Nonetheless, it is possible for the encoding to be other ([EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), for example), and the characters of the Latin alphabet may not be encoded in a contiguous sequence. This would cause problems for solutions that compare `char` values directly.

One solution is to create a string that holds valid input characters, and to use `strchr()` to search for the input in this string in order to validate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *valid_input = "ABCDEFGH";
    char input;

    printf("Enter a letter from 'A' - 'H': ");
    if (scanf("%c", &input) == 1) {
        if (input == '\0' || strchr(valid_input, input) == NULL) {
            printf("Input '%c' is invalid\n", input);
        } else {
            puts("Valid input");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This approach is portable, though solutions which compare ASCII values are likely to work in practice. Note that in the original code that I posted, an edge case was missed, as pointed out by [@chux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998649/condition-to-limit-between-2-characters/45998887#comment78964364_45998887). It is possible to enter a `'\0'` character from the keyboard (or to obtain one by other methods), and since a string contains the `'\0'` character, this would be accepted as valid input. I have updated the validation code to check for this condition.

Yet there is another advantage to using the above solution. Consider the following comparison-style code:

```
if (input >= 'A' || input <= 'H') {
    puts("Valid input");
} else {
    puts("Invalid input");
}
```

Now, suppose that conditions for valid input change, and the program must be modified. It is simpler to modify a validation string, for example to change to:

```
char *valid_input = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
```

With the comparison code, which may occur in more than one location, each comparison must be found in the code. But with the validation string, only one line of code needs to be found and modified.

Further, the validation string is simpler for more complex requirements. For example, if valid input is a character in the range `'A' - 'I'` or a character in the range `'0' - '9'`, the validation string can simply be changed to:

```
char *valid_input = "ABCDEFGHI0123456789";
```

The comparison method begins to look unwieldy:

```
if ((input >= 'A' && input <= 'I') || (input >= '0' && input <= '9')) {
    puts("Valid input");
} else {
    puts("Invalid input");
}
```

Do note that one of the few requirements placed on character encoding by the C Standard is that the characters `'0', ..., '9'` be encoded in a contiguous sequence. This *does* allow for portable direct comparison of decimal digit characters, and also for reliably finding the integer value associated with a decimal digit character through subtraction:

```
char ch = '3';
int num;

if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
    printf("'%c' is a decimal digit\n", ch);
    num = ch - '0';
    printf("'%c' represents integer value %d\n", ch, num);
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely true, but nevertheless it's very common that ASCII is used, I never saw something different on any machine yet. Anyways very good answer: +1!

Comment: @AndreKampling-- I have never personally encountered an issue with this, but I have heard of the problem arising in legacy systems, e.g., old institutional systems, that use EBCDIC.

Comment: @AndreKampling: This might due to looking at the wrong machines ... ;-)

Comment: Note: `input >= 'A' || input <= 'H'` works in ASCII and EBCDIC.

Comment: @chux-- well, yes, but not for `input >= 'A' || input <= 'J'` (if input conditions change) in EBCDIC; and possibly not for some exotic future encoding allowed by the Standard....

Comment: Missed corner: `if (scanf("%c", &input) == 1) {
        if (strchr(valid_input, input) == NULL) {` fails should the user enter a null character as that is reported as being between A-H.  Try `printf("%p\n", (void*)strchr("ABCDEFGH", '\0'));`.

Comment: @chux-- That corner case had entirely escaped my notice; updated.

Answer (score 4):

The if statement you present here is equal to:

```
if (input == -9) return 1;
```

which will `return 1` in the case of an `input` equal to `-9`, so there is no range checking at all.

---

To allow numbers from `0` to `9` you have to compare like:

```
if (input >= 0 && input <= 9) /* range valid */
```

or with the characters that you want (`A` to `H`)<sup>1</sup>:

```
if (input >= 'A' && input <= 'H') /* range valid */
```

---

If you want to `return 1` if the `input` is not in a valid range just put the [logical not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) operator (`!`) in front of the condition:

```
if (!(input >= 'A' && input <= 'H')) return 1; /* range invalid */
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You should take care of the used range if working with conditions that uses character ranges because the range needs an encoding that specify the letters in an incrementing order without any gaps in between the range ([ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) e.g.: `A = 65, B = 66, C = 67, ..., Z = 90`).
There are encoding where this rule breaks. As the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45998887/8051589) of @DavidBowling stated there is for example [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) (e.g.: `A = 193, B = 194, ..., I = 200, J = 209, ..., Z = 233`) which has some gaps in between the range from `A` to `Z`. Nevertheless the condition: `(input >= 'A' && input <= 'H')` will work with both encodings.
I never fall about such an implementation yet and it is very unlikely. Most implementations uses the [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) for which the condition works.
Nevertheless his answer provides a solution that is working in every case.

Comment: "There are encoding where this rule breaks." --> What character encoding breaks this for `input >= 'A' && input <= 'H'`?  Certainly ASCII and EBCDIC work.

Comment: @chux: Thank you! Right it not well written by me. But on other ranges it fails: e.g.: `I = 200 and J = 209`. I changed that :D.

Answer (score 4):

It's as simple as:

```
if(input >='A' && input<='H') return 1;
```

C doesn't let you specify ranges like `0 - 9`.
In fact that's an arithmetic expression "zero minus nine" and evaluates to minus nine (of course).

**Nerd Corner:**
As others point out this is not guaranteed by the C standard because it doesn't specify a character encoding though in practice all modern platforms encode these characters the same as ASCII. So it's very unlikely you will come unstuck and if you're working in an environment where it won't work you'd have been told!

A truly portable implementation could be:

```
#include <string.h>//contains strchr()

const char* alpha="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const char* pos=strchr(alpha,input);
if(pos!=NULL&&(pos-alpha)<8) return 1;
```

This tries to find the character in an alphabet string then determines if the character (if any) pointed to is before 'I'.

This is total over engineering and not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: EBCDIC _does_ exist in the real, modern, programming world; it is just not common. Your example using `strchr()` is more complex than it needs to be. I provide reasons beyond portability for choosing `strchr()` over direct comparison in my answer.

Comment: @david How is this good answer more complex than needed?  It correctly tests for all possible `input` unlike [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45998887/2410359)

Comment: You may or may not be told, depending on your position in a project. You may be the one who has to know these things. Mainframes can run for a long time, so old IBM mainframes are the likely place to encounter such issues (not unheard of). The Standard also would allow for new encodings in the future, which may not match with ASCII here; still, I don't disagree about the utility of updating the Standard in this regard (just not holding my breath).

Comment: @DavidBowling It exists but it is so far off the mainstream that as I did say the OP would have been told their platform was exotic and if they weren't shouldn't worry. I don't agree with your portability argument. It's over engineered and changing a single if statement is as easy as changing some defined string constant. If it's re-used remove it to a function. Performance may not be relevant but `strchr` will be much slower than a couple of integer comparisons.

Comment: @chux David's answer just checks `strchr("ABCDEFHI",input)!=NULL` which certainly covers the job. I'm not really proposing the code I've shown. I'm really hinting at a portable way of getting letter number from a character without the `input-'A'` ASCII assumption.

Comment: I know I'll get flamed for it but C is nearly 50 years old and I think we should start accepting some things are fairly obsolete. Computers use twos-complement and are ASCII compatible and anything that isn't is weird or old or both.

Comment: @Persixty This answer's `pos!=NULL&&(pos-alpha)<8` given the proper answer when `input==0`.  `strchr("ABCDEFHI",input)!=NULL` does not.

Comment: @chux Well spotted. You're always on top of the edge cases.

Comment: Maybe we're splitting hairs here. Note that I never said that the comparison approach is "wrong"; I just wanted to point out some possible issues, in the interest of strict portability (which, granted, may not be of interest to OP, but may be to others), and some other possible benefits of the search method. Agree about performance penalty, but I still think that is is simpler to modify a verification string. It is more intuitive than writing the correct conditional, especially when the requirement is more complex, e.g., "MESPH", or some other mix of input characters.

Comment: @DavidBowling All fair points. I think the problem is we're discussing software maintainability and the original question is from someone who is sufficiently novice to not know that `0 - 9` doesn't specify a range. My real point is in the answer "This isn't the answer you're looking for" and think discussions of exotic character sets will unhelpfully blow their mind. 
There's a tendency on SO for beginners to be provided with answers that while technically excellent are way over OPs knowledge level.

Comment: @chux-- I meant that this use of `strchr()` is more complex than it needs to be because it could use a string that only contains valid characters, but instead uses a string of all UC Latin alphabet characters with arithmetic and magic numbers to determine validity. In this version, the method is less easily modified for new requirements, and it seems less easily understood (though it did catch the corner case that I missed).

Comment: @Persixty-- In our exchanges earlier, I certainly did not mean to give the impression that this is a bad answer; I only wanted to defend my own answer. While I don't entirely agree that the approach I showed is over-engineered, I do agree that this is probably not what OP wants. Yet I do think there is value in discussing these sorts of concerns here; I stand by my right to present such information for whatever use it may have, as well as your right to critique it. IAC, yours is a good answer. Have an upvote, +1 :)

Comment: @DavidBowling And I wasn't being critical of it (here, have an upvote!). My comment about over engineering is that it is over engineered for the question. I agree there are situations where that is an appropriate level of engineering. I've seen code (e.g. where it's looking at contract prefixes to understand (say) validation rules) that works all ways and things like `if((prefix>='A' && prefix<='H') || prefix=='P') { /*...*/ } else if (prefix=='N'){//...'` is probably the **least** elegant solution (and not uncommon!).